# How to animate vertical counter to current active number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 slides and in the beginning when first slide is active counter should show `01 / 05`. When later slides change, for example if third slide becomes visible then `<span>03</span>` gets class `active` (I have already done this) and counter should show `03 / 05`.

How do I animate current slide number into  position?

I have played with `transform: translateY()`, is there a more optimal way than this? If not, how do I listen to children (when a span gets active class) and calculate the right pixel size for transform?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zajBbN

CSS

```
.info {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 35px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  &__current {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 200ms;
    transform: translateY(-47px);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="info">
    <span class="info__current">
        <span>01</span>
        <span>02</span>
        <span class="active">03</span>
        <span>04</span>
        <span>05</span>
    </span>
    <span class="info__separator">/</span>
    <span class="info__total">05</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an infinite loading loop when I visit the codepen. I'm using Chrome v67.

Comment: I also get that sometimes, I am not sure why but it works fine when I change user in Chrome (other user or to guest)